# How to insert a MathType equation in an Excel chart with good resolution?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, copy-paste, high-resolution, mathtype

I can copy a MathType equation from MS Word and paste it on an Excel chart after selecting it. However, the resolution is poor. How can I get a better resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enlarge the equation image in Word before copying it. The more you enlarge it the better the resolution. I enlarge it only enough to get the desired result not to risk unnecessarily enlarging the size of the Excel file.